# centering components with css/html/angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

Hi my project is located at

https://stackblitz.com/github/skwallace36/temprepo

I am trying to center the trees/and or the the two tree names at the top...

I am struggling to achieve this due to the crazy structure of the angular components and other wacky css/html which I'm not really too good at...

I don't think it would be helpful to post css/html snippets because I'm honestly not sure where I should try to achieve this, or if something I already have is preventing it...

I have tried all sorts of center, margin, etc solutions in so many different places.. I cannot find a solution

SOS and thank you very much for checking out my stack blitz

Comment: you want to make that treeconatiner component center of the page

Comment: @chellappan yeah... try clicking between the trees at the top. I want them to somehow be centered no many how many nodes and such. I'm just not sure if it's possible because hypothetically it could have a ton of nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `style.scss` file

```
.treebuttoncontainer {
  text-align: center;
}

.trees {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vhp7ei)

Comment: you should probably add some additional scoping from their parent container to avoid CSS collisions with other items

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: hey man could you checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430443/struggling-to-keep-content-on-page-in-angular-project-css-html?