# struggling to keep content on page in angular project css/html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

thank you for reading... this is killing me inside

So my issue can be experienced here on stackblitz...

https://stackblitz.com/github/skwallace36/temp

Clicking on the bottom right square of a node adds a child...

The issue occurs when repeatedly pressing this add child. When many children are added to a node the nodes on the left start to fly off of the page, while the nodes to the right expand correctly with a scrollbar. I think it may have to do with some overflow property, but I CANNOT FOR THE LIFE OF ME figure out where things should be changed.

the way I'm centering things is with

```
align-content: center
```

in tree.component.scss

Comment: remove the `justify-content: center;` on `.trees` class

Comment: yeah but then it's just constantly pulled to the left... for smaller trees it looks funky and would be nicer if it was centered. Try clicking on the Tinbank Inc Production... it's very awkwardly to the far left. - thanks for your response though.

Comment: I have read you question 4 time but I don't figer out what is the problem

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi check the tree in the first tab.. it goes outside left edge of the browser... it should be contained in the browser and the tree should be aligned center...

Comment: remove `justify-content: center;` on `.trees` and add `.trees .ng-star-inserted { margin: auto; }` - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fihpvr?file=src/app/treepane/treepane.component.scss

Comment: that seems to be helping @dysfunc but any idea why it creates the vertical scroll bar and cuts off the bottom? It's due to the use of the bottom: -10 in my .add-button in node.component.scss.... but how the hell do I get rid of that without messing with positions of other stuff? You are helping a ton.

Comment: (when I move it to not bottom: -10 it works so amazingly!!!)

Comment: I think I can fix it by adding a margin to the cards and just making the tree connecting lines a little longer. stay tuned lol

Comment: JK just needed to add a margin to the bottom of the card. thanks man!!!

Comment: np. let me know if you have any other issues